# PHP: remove small words from string ignoring german characters in the words

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create slugs for urls.

I have the following test string :

```
$kw='Test-Tes-Te-T-Schönheit-Test';
```

I want to remove small words less than three characters from this string.

So, I want the output to be

```
$kw='test-tes-schönheit-test';
```

I have tried this code :

```
$kw = strtolower($kw);
$kw = preg_replace("/\b[^-]{1,2}\b/", "-",  $kw);
$kw = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $kw);
$kw = trim($kw, '-');
echo $kw;
```

But the result is :

```
test-tes-sch-nheit-test
```

so, the German character ö is getting removed from the string
and German word Schönheit is being treated as two words.

Please suggest how to solve this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, your string is not UTF-8. With Umlauts/NON-ASCII characters and regex I think, its easier first to encode to UTF-8 and then - after applying the regex with u-modifier (unicode) - if you need the original encoding, decode again (according to local). So you would start with:

```
$kw = utf8_encode(strtolower($kw));
```

Now you can use the regex-unicode functionalities. \p{L} is for letters and \p{N} for numbers. If you consider all letters and numbers as word-characters (up to you) your boundary would be the opposite:

```
[^\p{L}\p{N}]
```

You want all word-characters:

```
[\p{L}\p{N}]
```

You want the word, if there is a start ^ or boundary before. You can use a positive lookbehind for that:

```
(?<=[^\p{L}\p{N}]|^)
```

Replace max 2 "word-characters" followed by a boundary or the end:

```
[\p{L}\p{N}]{1,2}([^\p{L}\p{N}]|$)
```

So your regex could look like this:

```
'/(?<=[^\p{L}\p{N}]|^)[\p{L}\p{N}]{1,2}([^\p{L}\p{N}]|$)/u'
```

And decode to your local, if you like:

```
echo utf8_decode($kw);
```

Good luck! Robert

Answer (score 1):

Your `\b` word boundaries trip over the `ö`, because it's not an alphanumeric character. Per default PCRE works on ASCII letters.

The input string is in UTF-8/Latin-1. To treat other non-English letter symbols as such, use the [`/u` Unicode modifer](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
$kw = preg_replace("/\b[^-]{1,2}\b/u", "-",  $kw);
```

I would use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) or `/e` btw, and instead search for `[A-Z]` for replacing. And `strtr` for the dashes or just `[-+]+` for collapsing consecutive ones.

Comment: Hi Mario, You wrote: I would use preg_replace_callback or /e btw, and instead search for [A-Z] for replacing. And strtr for the dashes or just [-+]+ for collapsing consecutive ones. can you please show how? Thanks.