# Regex again - removing small words from a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all words less than 3 characters long from a string.  I've found similar questions e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639675/php-remove-small-words-from-string-ignoring-german-characters-in-the-words) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628958/remove-small-words-using-python), but the accepted answers don't seem to work for me.

I have a string eg. "**abc d ef**"

and I want to achieve "**abc**"

The (JS) code I'm currently using is:

```
  var myString = "abc d ef";
  myString = myString.replace(/\W*\b\w{1,2}\b/, "");
```

... but this returns "**abc ef**" and is only removing the first instance of a small word.  *Do I need a "+" in there somewhere to allow multiple occurrences?*

Are there any regex gurus that would be able to help please?

I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRKUu/2/).

Comment: try something like /\b\w{1,2}\b/g

Comment: What happens when you run `myString = myString.replace(/\W*\b\w{1,2}\b/, "");` twice? do you only get "abc" back?

Comment: @Izzy yes that works, it was the global modifier that made it continue searching.

Comment: thanks @dandavis too for your answer too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is to add the global modifier to the regex. `g` and you're golden.

```
var myString = "abc d ef";
    myString = myString.replace(/\W*\b\w{1,2}\b/g, "");
alert(myString);
```